# CSS transform: translate not working on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad

I've made a simple under construction website which has an image and some text centred in the middle of the page like following:

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <span id="wip">Under Construction</span>
        <img id="image" src="katte.jpg">
        <span id="text">Glæd dig, her åbner katteboxen.dk i foråret 2015. Vi glæder os til at forkæle din kat med en spændende pakke hver måned.</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    max-width: 1230px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#image {
    width: 100%;
}
#text {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: block;
}
#wip {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: block;
}
```

Link: http://katteboxen.dk/

Everything is working good except when it comes to iPads. The content is showing like when for example the css rule `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` wasn't applied for the container. What are the alternatives for fixing this issue? Any guidance or feedback is more than welcomed.

Comment: Care to share a screenshot? :)

Comment: @Rvervuurt [link](http://i.imgur.com/yHvcA0n.jpg) :D

Comment: Himanshu was faster (I was still trying it out). His solution works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

transform property are browser based property set -webkit-transform, -moz-transform, -o-transform .... ans so set it according to your i-pad browser i this it will solve the problem

or just use

```
margin-left:-50%;

margin-top:-50%;
```

Comment: I can confirm this works. http://jsfiddle.net/z2j0hmr5/ (opened it on my iPad) Although you might want to do some repositioning.

Answer (score 6):

You might need to try browser specific prefixes for transform property, so:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

should do the trick.

For reference have a look [here](http://css3please.com/)